# ¿Como enviar correo con archivo adjunto en Xamarin.android?

Tags: c#, webservice, email, xamarin.android

Estoy desarrollando una App en Xamarin para android la cual genera un PDF que queda guardado en una carpeta oculta del dispositivo.

Actualmente utilizo un `WebService` para enviar el correo pero no llega con el PDF adjunto.
Estoy usando un `WebService` porque necesito que este correo se envíe de manera automática sin ninguna interacción con el usuario y los ejemplos que había encontrado en internet por lo general abrían gmail u otro diálogo el cual pedía que el usuario envíe el correo.

La excepción que me devuelve el debug es:

> System.IO.IOException: The network path was not found.

Obviamente esta excepción se produce ya que al WS le paso como argumento la ubicación (en el dispositivo) del PDF y el WS no puede encontrar dicho archivo ya que la ubicación recibida no existe en el servidor donde se encuentra el WS.

Mi pregunta es **¿Cómo puedo hacer para pasarle el PDF al WebService y que se envíe el adjunto?**

Dejo aquí el código que uso para enviar el correo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Web;

namespace Servicios.Clases
{
    public class cmSendMailCcopy
    {
        public string mailTo;
        public string mailCopy;
        public string mailFrom;
        public string mailSubject;
        public string mailBody;
        public string mailAuthentication;
        public string mailPassword;
        public string mailSmtpServer;

        public void Send(string mailTo, string mailCopy, string mailFromAddress, string mailFromName,
                     string mailSubject, string mailBody, string mailAuthentication, string mailPassword,
                     string mailSmtpServer, int mailPort, List<string> mailAttachment = null)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

                string mailDe = mailFromAddress;
                string deNombre = mailFromName;
                string mailPara = mailTo;
                string mailCopia = mailCopy;
                string asunto = mailSubject;
                string mensaje = mailBody;
                string mailAutenticacion = mailAuthentication;
                string mailContra = mailPassword;
                string mailSmtp = mailSmtpServer;
                int mailPuerto = mailPort;
                List<string> mailAdjunto = mailAttachment;

                try
                {
                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
                    {
                        Host = mailSmtp,
                        Port = mailPuerto,
                        EnableSsl = false,
                        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(mailDe, mailContra),
                        Timeout = 3000
                    };

                    MailMessage correo = new MailMessage(mailDe, mailPara, asunto, mensaje);
                    correo.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    correo.CC.Add(mailCopia);

                    if (mailAdjunto != null){
                        foreach (var item in mailAdjunto)
                        {
                            if (System.IO.File.Exists(item)){
                                correo.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(item, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    smtp.Send(correo);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                throw (exc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución al problema, lo voy a detallar en los siguientes pasos:

1- El ultimo argumento que recibe es un `List<string>`, en lugar de eso debería ser `List<byte[]>`

2- Antes de llamar al WebService, hay que convertir el PDF en byte[], para eso hacemos lo siguiente:

```
//Creamos una List<byte[]>
List<byte[]> adjuntos = new List<byte[]>();
//Definimos un array de tipo byte el cual va a contener los bytes del PDF
byte[] adjArreglo = File.ReadAllBytes(pdfAdjunto);
//Agregamos los bytes del PDF a la Lista
adjuntos.Add(adjArreglo);
```

3- En el programa que envía el correo, hay una sentencia `if (mailAdjunto != null)`, dentro de este `if` ponemos lo siguiente:

```
//Recorremos toda la Lista
foreach (var item in mailAdjunto)
{
    Por cada elemento de la lista, convertimos los byte[] en Stream
    Stream str = new MemoryStream(item);
    //Llamamos al Attachments.Add() con el steam, el nombre que tiene el PDF y el tipo de archivo (en este caso PDF)
    correo.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(str, "Test.pdf", MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf));
}
```

Con esto ya se envía el correo con el PDF adjunto.
El paso 3 directamente se puede hacer sin el Stream, pero en el mail en lugar de mostrarte "Test.pdf" el nombre del archivo adjunto se va a llamar como la ruta entera de donde se encuentra guardado el pdf.